# Make custom JTableModel to listen to changes in ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I got a list of Customers. Each Customer has a List of Accounts and each Account got a List of Transaction.

Recently I have been implementing import/export functionality to my program using ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream. This works and it saves everything and loads correctly.

My issue is that the JTable does not update automatically once the ArrayList has been changed (I have created a custom JTableModel which currently only sets each cell to be non-editable. Is there any listener that fits my needs? My CustomJTableModel extends DefaultTableModel.

I got the trigger to load/save in a custom MainMenu class that contains a JMenuBar and it does not directly know about the TableModel or the JTable (otherwise i could do a "cheap" way and just add it again).

There are methods such as fireTableDataChanged but that only listens to the JTable itself.

Not sure if I need to post any code, thought it was maybe a simple issue and that there is a suiting Listener out there.

Comment: it is probably that there is a flaw in the implementation. If you look below to my answer you will be able to solve your problem without any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for your problem would be to implement (Java observer interface ) in your JTable Class and implement (Java observable interface) in your class that exploits and modifies the ArrayList. This way, every time a change occurs to your the arrayList, update method will be invoked and JTable will be updated in consequence.

Here is a tutorial that details on my above explanation

```
public class JTable implements Observer
{

// this is the method that will be invoked everytime a change has occured.
 public void update(Observable obs, Object obj)
   {
      // To implements as required
   }

}

public class Store implements Observable
{
   ArrayList<Customers> listOfCustomers;

 public void setValue(Customer n)
   {
      this.listOfCustomers.Add(n);
      setChanged();
      notifyObservers(); // this will notify your JTable
   }
}
```

This is just a start of how to implement the system.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I can thumbs this up? It helped and i managed to get it to work.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you can give me credit me since it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that the JTable does not update automatically once the ArrayList has been changed

Well you should not be making changes to the ArrayList.

The ArrayList should be used as the data structure for your TableModel. Then if you want to make changes to the ArrayList (ie adding/removing rows) then this should be done via the TableModel.

See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on creating a custom model using this approach.

Now, on the other hand, if your problem is that a property of the Object that is stored in the ArrayList changes, then yes, you need to use the `Observer` pattern.